# How do asp.net core 3.1 console App add AddHealthChecks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to add HealthCheck to console App
There is currently a way to add HealthChecks but cannot join MapHealthChecks

```
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHealthChecks();
                });
```

I want to add the following equation code

```
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            });
```

I try join but ConfigureWebHostDefaults not found

Comment: Exactly what version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions` are you using?

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks Version 3.1.32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my testing and checking the official documentation, I found that the `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` method exists in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref`. When adding this package manually, I got the following error message.

#### So through testing we can conclude that we cannot use ConfigureWebHostDefaults in Console App.

[image]

**Suggestion**

We can use projects based on .Net 6+, and the configuration will be simpler. Here is the repo [NetCoreTemplates / selfhost](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost).